# Android camera setPreviewSize

Tags: android, android-camera, samsung-mobile

I am trying to record a video on a Samsung Galaxy S2. I have used the usual calculations to figure out the best preview dimensions and this has returned 720x480 or 800x480 depending on algorithm. The full list returning from `getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes()` looks like this:

> "640x480", "720x480", "800x480", "320x240", "176x144"

Setting these previews looks fine in the beginning. It seems to be recording the video, however after stopping the camera there's no video captured.

If I get height and width values from `CamcorderProfile.get(mCameraId, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);` and set those values for my previewsize (1920x1080) (which should not be supported as it's not in the list?), the recording works fine. This is really puzzling.

There are no errors I can see in logs, it's just not recording the video...

Answer (score 1):

```
getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes()
```

gives you the preview sizes for the camera, not the recording sizes, or pictures sizes.

for recording a video, there are other supported sizes as for pictures, which you could see in the docs of:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/CamcorderProfile.html

to get the supported video sizes just call:

```
getParameters().getSupportedVideoSizes()
```

so you need to set both, the preview and the recording size.

how you could do this, in answered here:
[How to record video of particular width and height on samsung device android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20245625/how-to-record-video-of-particular-width-and-height-on-samsung-device-android)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'll have a read through the linked post. Quick question though - getSupportedVideoSizes added in API11, is there an alternative for API10? Also I do undertand that preview, video and picture sizes are 3 different things - I just don't understand why setting a legal previes size returned by getSupportedPreviewSizes doesn't work when setting preview size to values in camera profile (which should be just for video right?) - does

Comment: this depends on nativ implementation of camera (maybe samsung made some default assumptions) , it could be that it won't work on all devices. 
there is no alternative for API 10, the Camera is just a wrapper for native calls. so it isn't easy to create a support lib for it that works on older versions across lots of devices.